# Why Matlab wants such giant amount of memory?

Tags: matlab, memory, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to learn neural net that is 289x300x1. E.g. input vector is 289 elements, 300 hidden neurons, 1 class-output.

So

```
net = feedforwardnet(300);
net = train(net,X,y,'useParallel','yes','showResources','yes');
```

gives error

> Error using nn7/perfsJEJJ>calc_Y_trainPerfJeJJ (line 37) Error
>   detected on worker 2. Requested 87301x87301 (56.8GB) array exceeds
>   maximum array size preference.

**X** is an array of size 289x2040, type of elements is double. 
**y** is an array of size 1x2040, type of elemetns is double.

I dont understand why matlab wants so much of memory for such small task. Weights need to be stored = 289 * 300 * 64 bytes which is ~5.5 MB.
And how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to a combination of a few things:

1. The number of neurons into your hidden layer is rather large.... are you sure 300 features / neurons is what you need?  Consider breaking down the problem to fewer features... a dimensionality reduction may be fruitful, but I'm just speculating.  However, from what I know, a neural network of 300 hidden neurons should be fine from experience, but I just brought this point up because that hidden neuron size is rather large.
2. You have too many inputs going in for training.  You have 2040 points going in and that's perhaps why it's breaking.  Try breaking up the dataset into chunks of a given size, then incrementally train the network for each chunk.

---

Let's assume that point #1 you can't fix, but you can address point #2, something like this comes to mind:

```
chunk_size = 200; %// Declare chunk size
num_chunks = ceil(size(X,2)/chunk_size); %// Get total number of chunks
net = feedforwardnet(300); %// Initialize NN

%// For each chunk, extract out a section of the data, then train the
%// network.  Retrain on original network until we run out of data to train
for ii = 1 : num_chunks
    %// Ensure cap off if we get to the chunk at the end that isn't
    %// evenly divisible by the chunk size
    if ii*chunk_size > size(X,2)
        max_val = size(X,2);
    else
        max_val = ii*chunk_size;
    end

    %// Specify portion of data to extract
    interval = (ii-1)*chunk_size + 1 : max_val;

    %// Train the NN on this data
    net = train(net, X(:,interval), y(interval),'useParallel','yes','showResources','yes'));
end
```

As such, break up your data into chunks, train your neural network on each chunk separately and update the neural network as you go.  You can do this because neural networks basically implement [Stochastic Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) where the parameters are updated each time a new input sample is provided.